# How to deserialize json to enum with jackson in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an interface with name Field as below:

```
public interface Field {
}
```

This interface is in the module **A**.
I have an enum called BField which is in module **B** and is implemented as below:

```
public enum BField implements Field {
    SOME_FIELD
}
```

There is a class named C in the module **A** as below:

```
public class C implements Serializable {
    private Set<Field> f;

    public Set<Field> getF() { return f; }
    public void setF(Set<Field> f) { this f = f; }
}
```

I have a REST method as below:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.Post, value="/save")
@ResponseBody
public void save (@RequestBody C c) {
    //save c
}
```

I send this JSON object to this method:

```
{
    "f": ["SOME_FIELD"]
}
```

then I get HTTP 400 bad request error code with the following exception log:

> abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type
>   information

The hierarchy of the modules is module **B** is dependent to module **A**. I tried to use @JsonTypeInfo but the dependency between modules works as a limit and does not let me to use BField.class in the @JsonSubTypes annotation for the field f in class C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I find the solution.

1. I remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in my context
2. Add `@JsonDeserialize(as = EnumSet.class)` annotation for field `private Set<Field> f;` in class C.
3. create a class called JsonBFieldDeserializer in module **B** as below:

   ```
   public class JsonBFieldDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Field> {
       public JsonBFieldDeserializer() {
           this(null);
       }
       public JsonBFieldDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
           super(vc);
       }
       @Overrid
       public Field deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext dC) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
           JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree();
           String text = node.asText();
           return BField.valueOf(text);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a class called BConfiguration in module **B** as below:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class BConfiguration extends WebMVCConfigurationSupport {
       protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverters<?>> converters){
           converters.add(convert());
           addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
       }
       @Bean
       MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter convert(){
           MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
           ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
           SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
           module.addDeserializer(Field.class, new JsonBFieldDeserializer());
           objectMapper.registerModule(module);
           converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
           return converter;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Be careful to use **fasterxml** jackson **not** codehaus library!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the `enum`, it's the `Set` and the `Field` interfaces.

You need to tell Jackson what kind of `Set` and what kind of `Field` you want, and you can do that by annotating that property with:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = EnumSet.class, contentAs = BField.class)
```

Comment: Excuse me I forgot to note that the interface Field has multiple implementations. For example BField in module B and DField in module D.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works when I test it with only one implementation of the interface Field, but I have to depend module A to module B, too. My problem  is a little different. First I don't want depend module A to module B, second interface Field has multiple implementations in multiple modules.

Comment: What you want is probably only possible if you collect Jackson pieces from your modules and aggregate them; one example is how Druid allows you to register custom parsers and other stuff: http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/modules.html